# Help when parent record is edited another child record is creating

Tags: process-builder

when a parent record is created a child record also has to create and when the same  parent record is edited the same child values has to be edited.
But in my case when a parent record is edited another child record is creating.

```
OR( 
    AND(  
        ISNEW(), 
        NOT( ISBLANK( [Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c].GR_Counterparty_Signatory_Email__c )  )
    ), 
    AND(  
        NOT(ISNEW()), 
        ISCHANGED([Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c].GR_Counterparty_Signatory_Email__c)
    )
)
```

[image]

[image: if edit counter party signatory email,we can see in docusign recipients related list muliple records are creating .]

Comment: you should probably share a screenshot of your PB actions that are executed when this formula evaluates to "TRUE". In PB Flows you can update related child records to a parent record via "Update Records" Action. You can either update all children or limit them based on field values

Comment: @RobertMéndez I have to create the child record with the given values in the action above and update with the same when the parent record is edited

Answer (score 0):

How I understood your use case, you want to create one child record for each parent and populate it with specific values from the parent. Any updates should update that one child record as well.

Currently your PB Flow is using the "Create Record" Action for that. That leads to the creation of a new child record whenever your entry criteria is fulfilled.

I would create a checkbox field on the parent ("has Child" or sth like it) and change the PB Flow so that it would distinguish between two scenarios:

1. Your formula is TRUE + HasChild field = FALSE

   - Create the Child record with the parent value ("Create Record" Action)
   - Update the Parent record to HasChild = TRUE ("Update Record" Action - on the parent)
2. Your formula is TRUE + HasChild field = TRUE

   - Update the child record with parent value ("Update Record" Action - on the child record)

If it should be possible for the parent to have multiple children but only one of those should receive the updates you have to flag it with an additional field and limit the Child Update in 2. by this flag.

Hope that helps

Comment: without creating the extra field it wont be possible ?